# How to properly extend TextInputLayout.java

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

```
    public class PhoneInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {
  public void setPhoneNumberEditText(TextInputEditText 
         phoneNumberEditText) {
      this.phoneNumberEditText = phoneNumberEditText;
  }

  private TextInputEditText phoneNumberEditText;
  public PhoneInputLayout(Context context ) {
    super(context);
  }

  public PhoneInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }



  @Override public void setError(@Nullable CharSequence error) {
    phoneNumberEditText.setPaddingRelative(phoneNumberEditText.getPaddingStart() - getPadding(R.dimen.account_info_margin),
        phoneNumberEditText.getPaddingTop(),
        phoneNumberEditText.getPaddingEnd(),
        phoneNumberEditText.getPaddingBottom());
    super.setError(error);

  }

  private int getPadding(int paddingId) {
    float scale = this.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (this.getContext().getResources().getDimension(paddingId) * scale + 0.5f);
  }
}
```

All of the view classes defined in the Android framework extend View. Your custom view can also extend View directlyThis code doesn't show the cursor on the field. I want to understand how to properly extend the TextInputLayout class

Comment: You didn't add phoneNumberEditText to PhoneInputLayout for child view in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to create a custom view for TextInputLayout.
The following is working well with cursor on the field.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:hint="Phone Number"
android:labelFor="@id/card_input_password"
android:paddingStart="12dp"
android:textColorHint="@color/text_tertiary_black"
app:errorEnabled="true"
app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextInputLayoutFlybuysTheme">

    <EditText
    android:id="@id/card_input_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top|start"
    android:inputType="phone" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: One example is encapsulating both views in a single easy to use view.